# How to deal with side effects of mocked method with JUnit/Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

This might be a dumb question or something obvious to figure out, but nevertheless, I'm really struggling to solve this.
Let's say we have the following logic within a method under test:

```
@Service
public class ServiceToTest() {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    public String testMethod() {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // eventParameters will be populated inside someService
        String result = someService.doLogic(parameters);
        // do something with the result here that doesn't really matter for this example
        String name = parameters.get("name").toLowerCase();
        return name;
    }
}
```

Inside `SomeService` the parameters map is populated with some values, like the "name" in this example. I would like to mock this service in my unit test.

Consider the following unit test snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceToTestTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ServiceToTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public ServiceToTest serviceToTest() {
            return new ServiceToTest();
    }

    @Autowired
    private ServiceToTest serviceToTest;

    @MockBean
    private SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void testShouldReturnJimmy() {
        given(someService.doLogic(Mockito.anyMap())).willReturn("whatever");
        String name = serviceToTest.testMethod();
        assertThat(name).isEqualTo("jimmy");
    }
}
```

When I execute this test I get a NullPointerException on this line:
`String name = parameters.get("name").toLowerCase();`, which makes sense as the method that should populate this map is mocked and `parameters.get("name")` is null. Let's also assume that I really want to have a String returned from `doLogic(parameters)`, so it cannot be the parameters map.

Is there a way to somehow instruct the mock object to populate the parameters map, or to mock the map object itself?
(The code examples here were written for this post on the fly, so please forgive me if there are any stupid mistakes that I haven't noticed while writing them ;-) )

Comment: There is a way. But this is a sign that the code should be refactored. Why not returning, from doLogic(), an object containing the result String, and a Map?

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but with all due respect, it seems a bit counterintuitive to me. Creating another object to store the object that I wanted to return from my method and the Map that I just wanted to enrich... 
The best way to refactor would be I guess is to create a dedicated public method in SomeService that would enrich/populate the Map and return it. That way I can easily mock what I want to get back in the Map.
I just did this and it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks JB for pointing me in the direction of refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using the controversial thenAnswer method.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-

But JB's comment is correct. This is not a great idea.